# How to pass and execute sql query statement using drill shell from script.sh?

Tags: bash, apache-drill

I have a script.sh file contains several sequential commands separated by &&. The last command is as the follow:

```
`    '/opt/apache-drill-1.12.0/bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=vm0,vm1,vm2;schema=hbase`
```

After the last command mentioned above get executed, drill shell will start. What I want to do is to pass this sql command

```sql
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(probeId,'UTF8') probe,CONVERT_FROM(galleryId,'UTF8') gallery, CONVERT_FROM(score,'INT_BE') score FROM tempTable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 500;
```

to be executed by drill through the script.sh. I have tried something like this:

```
echo`SELECT CONVERT_FROM(probeId,'UTF8') probe,CONVERT_FROM(galleryId,'UTF8') gallery, CONVERT_FROM(score,'INT_BE') score FROM tempTable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 500;`|\ /opt/apache-drill-1.12.0/bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=vm0,vm1,vm2;schema=hbase
```

but it did not work, only drill shell gets started; waiting for me to write the sql command to be executed. How can I pass it to drill shell automatically from script.sh? Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the drill shell, however, you probably should not be using the backticks after the `echo`.  The backticks are for command substitution and will try to execute the (shell) code within.  Try changing your backticks to double quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason , your answer fixed my problem.